# How can I access the current instance of my model when in the Admin Change Form?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a data management system for a publisher wanting to track sales. I have a model for the bookstores which stock the publisher's books, which includes a status field (from a status model) for each store. The status could be something like "not set", "order received" or "call back".

In addition to being able to view the current status, the client would also like to be able to view the status changes for a given store when inspecting the bookstore's data on the Admin Change Form: the status itself, the date and time of the status change, the user who made the change and some comments about the change. I have therefore created a status change model to store this data, and added an inline.

In the Admin Change Form for bookstores, I have disabled the status field (to prevent users changing the status without creating a status change record) and added a "Change status" link, which takes users to a form to allow them to create a new status change record. The problem I have been unable to solve is: How can I access the current bookstore instance so that I can pass the store id and its current status to the change status form?

I can get the id of the user without any problems from the request. I can get the id of the first bookstore in my database using self.model.objects.first(), but I haven't been able to find a way to get the id of the bookstore being viewed when the "Change status" link is clicked.

In models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Status(models.Model):
    DEFAULT_PK = 1
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Bookstore(models.Model):
    store_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    store_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=Status.DEFAULT_PK)


class StatusChange(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bookstore = models.ForeignKey(Bookstore, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes = models.TextField()
```

In admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet
from .models import Status, Bookstore, StatusChange
from .forms import StatusChangeForm


class StatusChangeFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(StatusChangeFormSet, self).get_queryset()
        return qs[:5]


class StatusChangeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StatusChange
    formset = StatusChangeFormSet
    fields =  ('date_time', 'user', 'status', 'notes')
    readonly_fields = ('date_time', 'user', 'status')
    can_delete = False
    max_num = 0
    ordering = ('-date_time',)


class BookstoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Bookstore
    list_display = ('id', 'store_code', 'store_name', 'status')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'store_code', 'store_name')
    ordering = ('id', )
    fields =('store_code', 'store_name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'description', 'status')
    inlines = [StatusChangeInline, ]

    # Disable the status field except if we are creating a new bookstore
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return self.readonly_fields + ('status',)
        return self.readonly_fields

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [path('statuschange/', self.change_store_status, name='statuschange'), ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def change_store_status(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            pass

        obj = self.model.objects.first()
        store_id = getattr(obj, 'id')
        store_status = getattr(obj, 'status')
        form = StatusChangeForm(
            initial={'user': request.user, 'bookstore': store_id, 'status': store_status}
        )
        payload = {"form": form}
        return render(request, "admin/change_status.html", payload)

admin.site.register(Bookstore, BookstoreAdmin)
```

This of course takes the user to the form allowing them to change the status... of the first bookstore in the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have path for bookstore change something like:
`/admin/<app_name>/bookstore/<pk>/change/`
I would suggest you keep this url configuration and create url for statuschange like:
`/admin/<app_name>/bookstore/<pk>/statuschange/`

Assuming your `StatusChangeForm` is:

```py
class StatusChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.StatusChange
        fields = ['user', 'bookstore', 'status',]
```

So in order to do that, you will need to adjust your `get_urls()` to accept `pk` of `bookstore`:

```py
def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [path('<int:pk>/statuschange/', self.change_store_status, name='statuschange'), ]
        return my_urls + urls
```

and modify your `change_store_status()` to receive that `pk` and use it when fetching `bookstore` instance:

```py
def change_store_status(self, request, pk):
        obj = self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)

        store_id = getattr(obj, 'id')
        store_status = getattr(obj, 'status')
        form = forms.StatusChangeForm(request.POST or None,
            initial={'user': request.user, 'bookstore': store_id, 'status': store_status}
        )

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

        payload = {"form": form}
        return render(request, "admin/change_status.html", payload)
```

Also you have to provide `pk` in your bookstore change template to direct user to correct form, like:
`{% url 'admin:statuschange' pk=original.pk %}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Please forgive my ignorance - I'm still very new to Django - but how would I go about creating the url for statuschange in the way that you suggest?

Comment: You said `added a "Change status" link, which takes users to a form to allow them to create a new status change record.`. I mean replace `href` attribute to the code I provided. Might not work if actual `object` instance named different, but try it first.

Comment: I tried it. But I get `'NoReverseMatch at /admin/stores/bookstore/1/change/
Reverse for 'statuschange' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/stores/bookstore/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/statuschange/$']`.

Comment: @MatthewJames hm, didn't check personally, but try `{% url opts|admin_urlname:'statuschange' opts.id %}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same error. Looking at similar problems/errors, I get the impression that I really should be supplying an extra line in urls.py to support the URL `/admin/<app_name>/bookstore/<pk>/statuschange/`. I'll keep poking around...

Comment: @MatthewJames did you try accessing url directly? `get_urls` does the same as in `urls.py`, you shouldn't change that. I'm sure it is working since it worked on my end.

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestions for solving this problem. I found out that commented-out code in the template still gets parsed, so when I tried `<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'statuschange' opts.id %}">Change Status</a>`, I was getting the same NoReverseMatch error. With the commented-out code removed, I get an Invalid filter error.

Comment: I reverted to your original idea of `<a href="{% url 'admin:statuschange' pk=object.pk %}">Change Status</a>`, but I still get the NoReverseMatch error. However, if I pass an actual value for the pk, say `<a href="{% url 'admin:statuschange' pk=1 %}">Change Status</a>`, it works. You mentioned that `pk=object.pk` might not work if the actual `object` instance was named different. I've tried various different substitutions for `object` without success. Is there any way to find out what the actual `object` instance is named?

Comment: Finally figured it out after poking around in `change_form.html`. What I needed was this: `<a href="{% url 'admin:statuschange' pk=original.pk %}">Change Status</a>`. Cheers for your help.

Comment: @MatthewJames great job! I've updated answer if anyone will use this answer.